# HTML5 App Storage Windows Phone 8

Tags: html, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I want to develop an html5 app for both windows 8 and windows phone 8.
What is the best storage technique, I thought about the following options:

- Local Storage
- IndexDB

Please tell me what storage mechanism to use? Can I use IndexDB in windows phone 8 *(unable to find any article talking about it with WP8)* ? Any idea of quota limit?

P.S. If you want to suggest any other storage technique then it is also fine.

**DETAILS**

IndexDB seems to be a good option, but 
[this link,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/12/19/using-html5-javascript-in-windows-store-apps-data-access-and-storage-mechanism-ii.aspx) confused me by talking about quota and saying

> Indexed Database, each app has a quota of 250MB. Among all apps on the device, the limit is 4% of the disk size or 20GB, whichever is smaller. For hard drives that are less than 30GB, the limit among all apps on the device is 375MB. Because of the overall quota among all apps, test your app to ensure it functions properly when it can store very little or even no data because other apps consume the overall quota.

Though in the end the article talks about creating contact app and uses IndexDB to store contact info.

Answer (score 0):

Use Phonegap. It has a local storage class you can make use of.

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage on windows phone is not the best one. Sometimes it didn't work.

I use the dataBase and it's work like a charm. Here is the link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

And then you can request it to get information. It's very helpfull and I think It could be a good starting point for you

Comment: Thanks, as of now I am not using PhoneGap, instead I'm developing it WP8 HTML5 App inside VS that comes by default when you install WP8 SDK. But I'll use it if it solves the problem. In the link you have provided,why WP is not listed in Supported Platform of openDatabase.